# Call Knockout JS Extender function after timeout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am currently trying to implement an autosave feature in a Knockout JS applcation using extenders. I want to call an autosave function when users stop typing in a field, not just when they tab out of it.

This is the logChange method I want to call when an observable gets updated.

```
    //KO Extender for logging changes and calling the autosave function
ko.extenders.logChange = function (target, precision) {

    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function (newValue) {
            debugger;
            var current = target(),
                valueToWrite = newValue,
                attName = precision;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
                //self.autoSave(attName, target());
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;

};
```

This is how I am setting up the observable in my viewmodel.

```
    self.controlCenter = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }, logChange: "ControlCenter" });
```

And this is my html markup for that observable

```
    <div class="pure-u-1-2 pure-u-md-1-4 pure-u-lg-1-8">
                        <label for="ddlControlCenter">Jurisdiction</label>
                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1 full-text" list="controlCenterList" data-bind="textInput: controlCenter" />
                        <datalist id="controlCenterList" data-bind="foreach: controlCenters">
                            <option data-bind="value: $data"></option>
                        </datalist>
                    </div>
```

The logChange method gets called, but it doesn't look like the rateLimit is being applied as the logChange gets called immediately on keypress.

Comment: You got the code from here right? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html
I took your code and added the 'loggedValues' code as well, changing it to your controlCenters variable. It works perfectly, along with the rateLimit delay.
Or are you saying it hits the debugger immediately?

Comment: Yes, that link is where I got the code from. I'm hitting the debugger in the logChange function immediately on keypress, so then my autosave function get's called as well. So if I were to enter the value "DIABLO" as the control center, it would try saving "D", "DI", "DIA", etc. I want the autosave to be called after the ratelimit.

Comment: It DOES get called after the ratelimit, even if it hits the debugger immediately. Ok, I'll just post the code I have, which includes what I guessed is the remainder of your code and minus the debugger. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I've updated the fiddle below. The mistake you were making was that you were calling a function inside the logChange function, right after updating the new value. But the concept of rateLimit is that the notification that the observable value was changed is sent after a delay *to all its subscribers*.

In other words, only the observable's subscribers are affected by the rateLimit, not anything inside the logChange function. So the correct way to do it would be to call your autoSave function inside the subscriber.

```js
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.autoSave = function(attName, value){
 console.log(attName + " is now = " + value);
}
self.precision = ko.observable();
                ko.extenders.logChange = function (target, precision) {

                    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
                    var result = ko.pureComputed({
                        read: target, //always return the original observables value
                        write: function (newValue) {
                            
                            var current = target(),
                                    valueToWrite = newValue;//,
                                    self.precision(precision);
                                    //attName = precision;

                            //only write if it changed
                            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                                target(valueToWrite);
                                //self.autoSave(attName, target());
                            } else {
                                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                                if (newValue !== current) {
                                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;

};

self.controlCenter = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }, logChange: "ControlCenter" });
self.controlCenters = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.controlCenter.subscribe(function (val) {
        if (val !== '')
            this.controlCenters.push(val);
            self.autoSave(self.precision(), val);
    }, this);
            }
            

             ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-u-1-2 pure-u-md-1-4 pure-u-lg-1-8">
            <label for="ddlControlCenter">Jurisdiction</label>
            <input type="text" class="pure-input-1 full-text" list="controlCenterList" data-bind="textInput: controlCenter" />
            <datalist id="controlCenterList" data-bind="foreach: controlCenters">
                <option data-bind="value: $data"></option>
            </datalist>
        </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the autosave function still get's called immediately, it does not get called after the rateLimit.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zx1mdbvb/

I've added the autosave function to the fiddle. In my code I would be posting the attribute name and value to the server, but for example's sake it just logs the attribute and value to the console. If you open the console you will see the value being written to as the keys are being pressed instead of after the rateLimit.

Comment: Updated the answer, and my fiddle